# Animate effect with jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to have animate effect with jquery

i have a animate script

```
$(popupID).animate({
    left: $(window).width() / 2 + popupMarginLeft
}, 500);
```

now i want to make changes in it like this

```
$(popupID).animate({left: $(window).width() / 2 + popupMarginLeft}, 
                         function() 
                             {
                                   $(popupID).fadeOut();
                             }, 500);
```

but then the script doesnt run, that means it has some error,

how can i solve it so that while the div slides towards right, it gradualy fades away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this script earlier

```
$(popupID).animate({left: $(window).width() / 2 + popupMarginLeft},function() 
                             {
                                   $(popupID).fadeOut();
                             }, 500 
                         );
```

and the final script that finaly worked is as follows

```
$(popupID).animate({left: $(window).width() / 2 + popupMarginLeft}, 500 , 
                         function() 
                             {
                                   $(popupID).fadeOut();
                             });
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be an error unless you define `fadeOut` function somewhere. Also animation duration should be the second argument. Try this:

```
$(popupID).animate({ left: $(window).width() / 2 + popupMarginLeft }, 500, function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgVbR/1/

Or if you want to animate both opacity and position:

```
$(popupID).animate({
    left: $(window).width() / 2 + popupMarginLeft,
    opacity: 0
}, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgVbR/

Comment: See updated answer, animation duration should be the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which element you want to fade out:

```
$(popupID).animate({
    left: $(window).width() / 2 + popupMarginLeft
},function(){
    $(popupID).fadeOut(500); // you can also use $(this) instead of $(popupID)
},
500);
```